# What is the difference between . and ./ in bash?

Tags: c, bash, shell, executable

Running this command (where `a.out` is a valid C executable):

```
. a.out
```

...results in this error:

> bash: .: a.out: cannot execute binary file

However, running the following command:

```
./a.out
```

...successfully executes the C binary executable.

Clearly, there are 2 types of executions happening here, what's different?

Comment: I would say those two dots are two separate commands - the first one is a [source or dot operator](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) while the second one just denotes the current directory (if `a.out` would be in a subdirectory `b`, you can run it using `b/a.out` - suddenly there's not dot but it's the same command as `./a.out`).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww Which itself is a duplicate of a much older question from [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/): [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i)!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The shell uses spaces to separate the command to run and its parameters.

In the first example, the command to run is `.` with a parameter of `a.out`.  The `.` command is a shell shortcut for `source`, which takes the name of a file containing shell commands as its first parameter and runs those commands in the current shell.  This command fails because `a.out` is a binary file, not a shell script.

In the second example, the command to run is `./a.out`, which means run the file `a.out` residing in the current directory.

Comment: I think `source` is a non-portable shortcut for `.`, not the other way around.

Comment: @gronostaj You're right. I thought `source` had been standardized, but I just checked POSIX and only `.` is in there.

Answer (score 7):

- `./program` runs a file named `program` located in your current working directory (`./`) (**in a new shell** for a shell script).
- `.` is the same as [**`source`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)), which runs a shell script **in your current shell**. Unlike `./program`, it can't be used to run binaries! As an example, you could use this command to run your `.bashrc` shell script, because you want this script to modify your **current shell**.

Comment: FYI `source` is a non-portable alias for `.`

Answer (score 4):

The first runs the `.` (dot) command with `a.out` as its argument. The dot command's job is to parse a text file as commands to execute inside the current shell environment. It gives you an error because `a.out` is not a text file.

The second executes `./a.out` which means "a program named `a.out` in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

`.`, alone, is the `source` command. It reads a file and executes it line-by-line, in the current shell - which, as you've seen, does not work for binary executables (as opposed to scripts).

In the context of a path, e.g., `./`, `.` stands for the current directory. So `./a.out` would mean "run the file a.out in the current directory".

Answer (score 2):

As everyone is saying:
`. myfile`: executes commands from `myfile`. (Like the `source` command in
C Shell)
`./myfile`: executes `myfile`

To elaborate, `.` is a command by itself (and `myfile` is passed as an argument to that), where `./` is a (relative) path to a file. When executing `./myfile` you are executing `myfile` which is an executable and is located in your current directory.

With that being said, when you want to execute some executable like `a.out` (which I assume is a C or C++ executable or something similar) you type `./a.out`.
When you have a bunch of commands in a "text" file and you want your shell to run those, you type `. myfile`. The most profound example of that is probably when you change the contents of `.bashrc` or `.profile` files and you want to "apply" your changes to the system.

Finally, do not confuse `.` command with `.` which is your current directory (as in the first result of `ls -a`)

Answer (score 2):

```
. a.out
```

This piece of code will execute the shell script present in the a.out using bash in the present terminal.

```
./a.out
```

This piece of code does not execute any command. (.) dot operator before a file represents a hidden file [For ex: .a.out]. Similarly (./) represents folders present in the current working directory. For ex :

```
cd ./documents
```

The above piece of code will change your directory to documents.